# Android fragment `setEnterTransition` doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to animate the showing of a fragment in a very basic way but it doesn't work:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFragment);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
  .hide(myFragment)
  .commit();

Slide slideRight = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
slideRight.setDuration(3000);

Slide slideLeft = new Slide(Gravity.LEFT);
slideLeft.setDuration(3000);

myFragment.setEnterTransition(slideRight);
myFragment.setExitTransition(slideLeft);
```

then later

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
  .show(myFragment)
  .commit();
```

But fragment just appears without any transition. I can't figure out why it doesn't animate.

**Edit:**
I ended up using the fragment support library with `setCustomAnimations` cause the native library doesn't support animation with relative values.
Also using the new API with `setEnterTransition` doesn't seem to work properly with `show/hide` and for some unknown reason worked only with `replace` which doesn't fit my needs.

Comment: I think you need to use overridePendingTransaction (unless that is activity-only, in which case ignore this comment)

Answer (score 0):

**setCustomAnimation** will do the trick.

```
FragmentManager.beginTransaction()

.replace(R.id.fragment, new Fragment)

.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_right).commit();
```